# Mock object issue

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, python-2.6, unittest2

I am using mock from voidspace and trying to execute some tests using unittest2 and the behaviour is strange. When i use "@patch.object(Test,'asd')" as a patch i get the mock object in the function arguments.
If i use @patch.object(Test,'asd',new_fun) as patch i dont get the one of the parameters.
I am using mock-1.0.1

Here you can see a small sample of code that exemplifies the problem.
I want to try to understand if this issue is a problem with the way i do the patch or if this is a problem in the library.

```
import unittest2 as unittest
from mock import patch

class Test:
  def asd(self, a, b =""):
     print "1"


class Test1:
   def kk(self, l):
      Test().asd("1")
   def kk1(self, l):
      Test().asd("1","1")

@patch.object(Test,'asd')
class MockClassUT(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_stat_process(self, my_mock):
        t = Test1()
    def test_stat_process1(self, my_mock):
        t = Test1()
    def test_stat_process2(self, my_mock):
        t = Test1()


def new_fun(*args, **kwargs):
  print "1"


@patch.object(Test,'asd',new_fun)
class MockClassUT1(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_stat_process(self, my_mock):
        t = Test1()
        t.kk("1")
        my_mock.assert_called_with("k")


testloader = unittest.TestLoader()
testnames = testloader.getTestCaseNames(MockClassUT)
suite = unittest.TestSuite()
for name in testnames:
    suite.addTest(MockClassUT(name))

testnames = testloader.getTestCaseNames(MockClassUT1)
for name in testnames:
    suite.addTest(MockClassUT1(name))

print testnames
unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

Comment: I get the error `TypeError: test_stat_process() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)` - is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behaviour. You have mocked it as a class decorator and you've also specified the new function `new_fun`. As such the mocked object won't be passed to each of the methods in the test class.

This means you can't expect `my_mock` as parameter there and it also means you can't write assertions using `my_mock`.

Furthermore, as an aside, your mocked method `new_fun` doesn't have the same signature as the method you're mocking (`asd`). The method `asd` expects `self, a, b=""` whereas `new_fun` doesn't have arguments so I expect an issue to come up there as well when the mocked method is called.

Comment: Ok, so i cannot execute assert_called_with when i pass a function to the mock?

Comment: @jpereira you can mocked and assert in any way you like but when you specify `new_fun` in the patch statement then the mock won't be passed to the test methods. So in there you won't have access to the mocked objects / methods.

Comment: So i cannot use assert_called_with i would need to do it myself inside the new_func, also corrected the code to do not have the problem of new_fun